# Bazel Build for Syntaxnet returns failure

Tags: bazel, syntaxnet

I am following the steps from Github repository of syntaxnet

After running

```
bazel test syntaxnet/... util/utf8/...
```

I am getting the following error:

> ERROR: Error downloading http://www.ijg.org/files/jpegsrc.v9a.tar.gz
> to
> /home/nikita/.cache/bazel/_bazel_nikita/40a11335a37800034c02daf7fa7a6e28/external/jpeg_archive/jpegsrc.v9a.tar.gz:
> Connection reset and referenced by
> '@tf//tensorflow/core/platform/default/build_config:platformlib'.
>
> ERROR: Loading failed; build aborted. INFO: Elapsed time: 1075.928s
>
> ERROR: Couldn't start the build. Unable to run tests.

Please suggest for the same

Comment: Which Bazel version are you using? Which OS?

Answer (score 0):

Originally if there is any error relating to bazel the handy way might be to reinstall bazel by following these steps:

Run the Installer

```
$ chmod +x bazel-version-installer-os.sh
$ ./bazel-version-installer-os.sh --user
$ rm bazel-version-installer-os.sh
$ sudo chown $USER:$USER ~/. cache/bazel/
$ export PATH="$PATH:$HOME/bin"
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a mac, skip that command and run this instead

```
bazel test --linkopt=-headerpad_max_install_names \
syntaxnet/... util/utf8/...
```